# Can't play offline audio

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have the following code

```
func getAudioUrl(book: Book) -> URL? {
    guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        print("Unable to access documents directory")
        return nil
    }
    let fileUrl = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test-audio-" + String(book.id) + ".mp3")
    
    guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.path) else {
        print("File does not exist")
        return nil
    }
    return fileUrl
}

  let fileURL = OfflineHandler.sharedInstance.getAudioUrl(book: currentItem as! Book)
  if (fileURL != nil) {
      let asset = AVAsset(url: fileURL!)
      avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
  }
  
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayerItem)
                
   audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
   audioPlayer?.volume = 1.0
   audioPlayer?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
                
   updateCC()
   isReadyToPlay = true
                
   audioPlayer?.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: ([.new, .initial]), context: nil)
    }
```

I'm trying to play an audio file stored in the Documents folder while the user has no Internet connection. I'm getting an error where the "status = unknown" (`override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {`)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How about:
`audioPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.status", options: ([.new, .initial]), context: nil)`
as the currentItem of the player might be nil at the moment when you add the observer?
EDIT: This post and the linked answer seem to cover your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31010985/3468171

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wait for a status change to start playback. So just try to play after the definition of the player item.

```swift
player.seek(to: .zero)    
player.play()
```

Maybe Apple doc also will help - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback/observing_playback_state

P.S. You don't need to make a player for each new load. You can replace the current item.